# Pickle File Memory Error - kelpto questoin

Tags: python, pickle, klepto

I'm getting a memory error when trying to pickle a large numpy array for a deep learning problem `shape: (7451, 1500, 1500, 1))`.  That stated, I see a few posts on `klepto` and read the docs but I'm not sure how to actually use `klepto` to save as a pickle file.

Can anyone break it down to a fifth grade level for me?

This is throwing the memory error:

```
pickle_out = open("X.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dumps(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Comment: The memory error you're getting is probably because the object you're trying to pickle is too large to hold in memory. I've only encountered this when parsing xml files (loading the whole file into memory then trying to parse it). I solved it by parsing iteratively. Pickle has a `dump` and `dumps` methods... Can you use `dumps` and write that to the file iteratively?

Comment: Hi @rong.  I tried dumps and got the following error: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.BufferedWriter)`  I added the code I used above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I faced similar problem I could solve it using joblib. You would need first to have sklearn library installed, which can be done for example with

```
pip install sklearn
```

That is just basic idea, to better know how to install it go to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
So, everything is pretty plane and is illustrated in following code

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np
array=np.array([0,1,2]) # thats explanatory array, you should use your instead

filename = 'array.sav'
joblib.dump(array, filename)
```

Then, to load back your data when u need to use it:

```
array = load(filename, mmap_mode='r')
```

Comment: Hi @Igorsharm.  Thank you.  Where does this save it to?

Comment: This should not work for the size of the stated array, unless you have a computer that has **a lot** of memory.

Comment: It would save to the current directory in a file named `array.sav`

Comment: @MikeMcKerns this just works for some large objects, which can not be saved by pickle even if they can be worked with, recently I used it to save 12GB sparse matrix, so it should work for the problem stated too. Anyway thanks for the explanation of the topic in the other answer, it was useful for me too!

Comment: It absolutely works for some large objects that can't be serialized with `pickle`, as it uses the `dump` that is included with `numpy`, and not `pickle`.  However, my point was that it will hit a size limit, which (depending on your machine) may be reached by the OP's given sized `array`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `klepto` author. If you are indeed just trying to pickle a `numpy` array, the best approach is to just use the built-in `dump` method on the `array` (unless the array is too large to fit within memory constraints).

Almost any code that does serialization uses one of the serialization packages (`dill`, `cloudpickle` or `pickle`), unless there's a serialization method built-in to the object itself, like in `numpy`.  `joblib` uses `cloudpickle`, and both `cloudpickle` and `dill` utilize the internal serialization that a `numpy` array itself provides (`pickle` does not use it, and thus the serialization bloats and can cause memory failures).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random((1500,1500,1500,1))
>>> a.dump('foo.pkl')
```

If the above still gives you a memory error, then `joblib`, `klepto`, `dill`, or otherwise really can't help you unless you break up the array into smaller chunks -- or potentially use a `dask` array (which is designed for large array data).  I think your array is large enough that it **should** cause a memory error (I tested it on my own system) even with the above optimally efficient method, so you'll either need to break the array into chunks, or store it as a `dask` array.

To be clear, `klepto` is intended for large non-array data (like tables or dicts), while `dask` is intended for large array data.

Another option is to use a `numpy.memmap` array, which directly writes the array to a file -- bypassing memory.  These are a bit complex to use, and is what `dask` attempts to do for you with a simple interface.